# Statistical distribution of a scaled complex Wishart matrix

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-matrix

Given that $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$, where $\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\mathbf{R})$ then $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H}$ is complex Wishart, i.e, $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H}\sim\mathcal{CW}(1,\mathbf{R})$.

- If the PDF of $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H}$ is known, then what
  is the distribution of $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{A}$,
  given that $\mathbf{A}$ consists of constants, Hermitian, singular
  and rank-1?
- What happens if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times m}$, i.e.,
  $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H}\sim\mathcal{CW}(m,\mathbf{A})$?